# Trying to concat a varchar table value with a string only returns the varchar

Tags: mysql, server, concatenation, varchar

I have a table called teachers with a column ,"username", which is a VARCHAR(50). I'm trying to concatenate values in that column with a string, "@gmail.com", and insert the concatenated values into a temp table that has one column, "email", which is VARCHAR(100).

Using `INSERT INTO temp SELECT CONCAT(username,'@gmail.com') FROM teachers;`

The code runs but only inserts the VARCHAR(50) username, not the '@gmail.com'. This is what happens for all values except 2 in the whole table.

Comment: Your code is fine. Can you give some example values that fail to get inserted? See this fiddle for a working example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4c388/1

Comment: @jpw For example 'mcrawbuck' works, however 'kalexander' doesn't. These are both the username values.

Comment: Can you check if the select part `SELECT CONCAT(username,'@gmail.com') FROM teachers` works fine?

Comment: @Rahul,@jpw I just started up MySQL Workbench on another computer,and saw that the correct values were actually inserted into the table. Seems like it was a problem with my other computer. Thanks for all the help!